# What happened to the third iteration of Yuki?

Tags: mirai-nikki

In the *Redial* conclusion to *Future Diary*, we see the 3<sup>rd</sup> iteration of Yuno living a normal life in the 3<sup>rd</sup> reality after the incident caused by the original Yuno and the 2<sup>nd</sup> Yuki saved her family's future. She has no recollection of Yuki at all in this world, even though she knows she is missing some very important memories.

This is almost identical to the state Yuki is in while trapped in the "ideal" world created for him by the original Yuno. However, she purposely removed herself from that false world, so it makes sense that Yuki can't even recall her name.

So what happened to the third iteration of Yuki that meant the 3<sup>rd</sup> Yuno couldn't remember him? He isn't seen at all in the final episode, so I'm confused as to what occurred in that regard. 1<sup>st</sup> Yuno wouldn't have had a reason to kill him as she wished to "try again" in that timeline, and Yuki, of course, wouldn't want to kill his own self.

Is there an explanation as to what happened to the 3<sup>rd</sup> timeline's Yuki?
And if he did still exist in that iteration, why can't the corresponding Yuno remember his identity at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In episode 26 from around 17:25 third world and all the diary holder are shown one by one. Everybody are living happy life. At19:50 Yuno is shown with her friend in some restaurant and she sees Yukiteru outside with his family and the girl [Moe Wakaba](http://myanimelist.net/character/73005/Moe_Wakaba). He is the 3rd universe Yuki. Looking from those clip, Yuki is happy with his family and Moe Wakaba.

Here is the [YouTube](https://youtu.be/ZbIBm0RjKtI?t=19m50s) video.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd iteration of Yuki and Yuno would've never met because she only approached him after she'd killed her parents and was looking for someone to cling to. Since that never happened, she didn't have feelings for him like the 1st Universe Yuno. The only reason she had memories was because of MurMur feeding her messages from inside the cage.

Answer (score 0):

I thought she said she finally got the courage to speak to Yuki when they had that survey, which implies she had feelings for him before that event. I don't see why she wouldn't still end up with Yuki in the third iteration.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Could you provide the source where she said that?

Answer (score 0):

So here's how me and my partner made it make sense....

We see 3rd Yukki with his fam and gf through the window as Yuno sits in the restaurant. That's the ONLY time we see 3rd Yuki.

We figure it's because when the school got trashed in the battle, all the kids got sent to different schools. Yuno ends up at school with Hinata and company, and Yuki ends up at a different school. That's why they never meet.

Because in this 3rd world, the timeline changed and Yuno never killed her parents. In the 2nd world (the one we watched all series) Yuno attached to Yuki AFTER she killed them, when they were last in class working on essays. None of this ever happened in world 3, so Yuno and Yuki never met.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a 27th episode. No, actually it's more like a special showing what happened after ep26. There they explain what happened to 3rd world Yuno ("Future Diary: Redial")

Comment: Try not to contradict yourself when giving answers. You could just stick to the information relevant to the topic of the question :)